# google maps wrong navigation starting point

Tags: google, geolocation, maps

I have a problem with Google maps.

Starting navigation on the app shows a grey point as a starting point. And a blue dot as my location, which is not the starting point. Just random point nearby (for this case last place i was search) or my home location (which is on other country).

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

I tried to clean cache ,delete the app and resetup the account. No nothing helps.

Setup other account fixed the problem but its not my account so i can use it. (Meaning that its no device problem).

Did any one have something like this before ? or maybe any solution ?

Comment: What location features do you have enabled? GPS and network?

Comment: High accuracy, GPS abd network. if i press the my location button the position is right...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed !

The problem was that i setup my account on other device (Nexus 7 - 2012 ) and this what makes the navigation problem. Removing it in the security settings fixed the bug..
Here is the link for removing your account on installed devices :

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6264236?hl=en